# Disable and enable function in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a text input in html that is affected by a function exectued by `.change()` events from different radios and checkboxes. I'm trying to make it so that if a user types into the input, this function will no longer run when a `.change()` event happens in the aforementioned radios and checkboxes (the user must still be able to use these radios and checkboxes). However, if the user leaves the input blank and clicks away, the script will run again. I hope is possible.
Here is my take on this so far:
Using`.prop('diabled'` isnt viable because it completely disables the input, making the user unable to type in it, so I need another solution.

```
$(function() {
  $('#burger-navn').on('input', function() {
    $("#burger-navn").prop('disabled', true);
  });
//When the input (#burger-navn) is typed into it should be "disabled"
  $('#burger-navn').focusout(function() {
    if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
      $("#burger-navn").prop('disabled', false);
    }
  });
//But if its clicked out of while its blank, it should be able to run again.
  $("#okseinput, #laksinput, #kyllinginput, #vegetarinput").change(function() {
    if (!$("#burger-navn").not(':disabled')) { //condition that tests
      navngenerator();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: check the http://api.jquery.com/one/ function, it may be of help if you really need to fire it only once, else you can bind with .on() and detach straight after the first execution with .off() by unbinding the eventHandler;

Answer (score 0):

To solve this I simply created a separate input tag that I could add and remove disabled attribute from, and check if it has that attribute.
So in html:

```
    <input id="burger-navn" type="text"/>
  <input id="toggle" disabled="disabled" style="display:none"/>
```

jQuery:

```
    var previousValue = $("#burger-navn").val();
  $("#burger-navn").keyup(function(e) {
      var currentValue = $(this).val();
      if(currentValue != previousValue) {
           previousValue = currentValue;
           $("#toggle").prop('disabled', false);
      }//This function will remove disabled from #toggle, when a user types into #burger-navn
  });
  $('#burger-navn').focusout(function() {
    if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
      $("#toggle").prop('disabled', true);
    }
  });
  if ($("#toggle").is(':disabled')) {
    navngenerator();
  }
  $("#okseinput, #laksinput, #kyllinginput, #vegetarinput").change(function() {
    if ($("#toggle").is(':disabled')) {
      navngenerator();
    }
  });
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$(selector).on('change', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
  // the selected field no longer does anything on change
});
```

is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Please, please check your answer for gross typographical errors before posting it. `event.precentDefault()` should be `event.preventDefault()` and `event.stopPropagination()` should be `event.stopPropagation()` .

Comment: @Terry thanks, i've seen it 5 seconds after submit ;)

Comment: I don't really understand how this would be implemented. From the way I understand it, it looks like this only lets you disable events from the same selector that exectues it. I need an event from one element disable functions that would be executed when other elements are changed. I'll add comments to clear up.